AWS REST API Gateway Refuses to return error code
I am using AWS REST API gateway, Non-Proxy integration, integrated with a Lambda function.
I am trying to return from my lambda any 5xx error code,
I have tried everything I can, but the API gateway keeps returning 200 every time
Lambda code:

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log("event: " + JSON.stringify(event));
    const returnStatus = parseInt(event.pathParameters.returnStatus);

    if (returnStatus === 511) { // Attempt 1
        throw new Error({
            errorMessage: `${returnStatus.toString()}`
        });
    } else if (returnStatus === 512) { // Attempt 2
        return {
            errorMessage: `${returnStatus.toString()}`
        };
    } else if (returnStatus === 513) { // Attempt 3
        return {
            headers: {'content-type': 'application/json', errorMessage: `${statusCode.toString()}`},
            errorMessage: `${returnStatus.toString()}`
        };
    }
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({time: Date.now()}),
    };
};


I have managed to reach within the 511, 512, 513 if statements, but still 200 is returned eventually from API gateway.
My REST API Gateway Integration Response has this config:

Method response status code: 200
regex: - (meaning default mapping: True)
Content Handling: Passthrough
Mapping template: $input.path('$').body

Method response status code: 500
regex: 5.*
Content Handling: Passthrough
Mapping template: (empty)


My REST API Gateway Method Responses:

200
500

I have tried:
For the 500 integration response: empty Mapping template, and also this Mapping templates
#set($context.responseOverride.status = 500)
Also tried this regex for 5xx: 5\d{2} (as mentioned in the docs)
Tested while entering each one of the if block statements, throwing and returning the errorMessage as a prop or a header BUT NOTHING WORKS, 200 is returned every single time!
Tries
Why? How can I return 5xx for crying out loud?
(And yes I've read the docs)

Looks like statusCode is defined nowhere, so the || will always resolve to 200

This is not the issue.  Even when lsmbda returns the above error objects. Still api gateway returns 200. Return statement exits the function. I've fixed the lambda code in question though. Thanks

Did you try to remove api gateway config?

I believe the error responses also need to include a statusCode property in order for APIGateway to catch them.  Try something like this:
if (returnStatus > 200) {
    return {
        // add status code to error response here
        // you could also use the variable "returnStatus"
        statusCode: 500,
        errorMessage: `${returnStatus.toString()}`
    };
}

